# Copy file from Windows mobile to XP through shared folder in Wi-Fi network

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-mobile, compact-framework, shared-directory

I have :

1. pc with xp pro (sp3)
2. samsung omnia with windows mobile 6.1
3. wi-fi network

in the xp i have shared folder.
is there way in csharp programming to copy from/to the shared directory using wi-fi ?

the important thing is: the c# program will run in the device

Comment: Did you find a way to do that?

Comment: Please see [this][1] answer for details on how to implement this.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3615863/375013